# Using handleChange inside a default function instead of a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use a Dropdown module with Semantic UI and react. The issue is all examples provided online use a default class App extends Component however I want to export default function App(). When I do this the I get a parsing error for the render() section, requiring a semicolon.

The below works very well but how can I implement it if the export was a default function instead?

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react'
import { Dropdown, Grid, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react'


export default class DropdownExampleControlled extends Component {
    state = {}
  
    handleChange = (e, { value }) => this.setState({ value })
  
    render() {
      const { value } = this.state
  
      return (
            <Dropdown
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder='Choose an option'
              selection
              value={value}
            />
      )
    }
  }
```

Writing const infront of the handleChange did not fix anything, it just made the "value" undefined later on. I am very unsure of how to use this because I am new to JS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. In any case, exporting as `default` likely has nothing to do with this. IIUC you are trying to convert `DropdownExampleControlled` from a class component to a function component?

Comment: @tomleb Yes that is exactly what I would like. I have an code that uses export default function App() and I am trying to use a Dropdown module in it, this requires handleChange but it does not seem to work the same way for classes as for functions.

Comment: Well yes, the syntax and methods are different between class components and function components. But I don't understand why you need to convert `DropdownExampleControlled` to a function component if it works fine as it is.

Comment: @tomleb I'm using an API and a bunch of other stuff that I have already set using a function, maybe converting them to a class would be easy but I'm very inexperienced in js at the moment so I would rather just change this one thing.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that a React app can have both class components and functions components within it. It doesn't have to be one or the other. If you want to convert the class component you have, that's fine, but it should work if you have both kinds as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **function components** rather than **class components** you have to utilise the **hooks** in React.
Heres how your code would look in a ***function component***

```
export default const DropdownExampleControlled = () => {
    const [yourState, setYourState] = useState({}); 
    // yourState being the name of the state and {} being your initial state
    const handleChange = (e, {value}) => {setYourState(value)}
    return (
        <Dropdown
          onChange={handleChange}
          options={options}
          placeholder='Choose an option'
          selection
          value={yourState}
        />
    )
}
```

Hooks are the newer way of persisting data, handling re-renders & more in modern React. If you want to learn more about how you can use hooks, here's a link to the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html